# Python webdriver selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm making a whatsapp bot and I need to know a way to put it in a loop until a new message arrives to respond it.

Any ideas?

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class WhatsappBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mensagem = "Mensagem teste" #mensagem a enviar
        self.grupos = ["Bloco de notas"] #grupos/user a enviar msg
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
        options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/arthurgomes/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default')
        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe', options=options)

    def EnviarMensagens(self): 
        # <span dir="auto" title="Bloco de notas" class="_3ko75 _5h6Y_ _3Whw5">Bloco de notas</span>
        # <div tabindex="-1" class="_3uMse">
        # <span data-icon="send" class="">
        print('dhuawdhauw')
        self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
        time.sleep(5)
        count = 0
        while count < 3:  
            for grupo in self.grupos:
                grupo = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='{grupo}']")
                time.sleep(0.2)
                grupo.click()
                chat_box = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3uMse')
                time.sleep(0.2)
                chat_box.click()
                chat_box.send_keys(self.mensagem)
                botao_enviar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-icon='send']")
                time.sleep(0.2)
                botao_enviar.click()
                time.sleep(0.2)
                print(count)
                count +=1
        if count >= 3:
            exit()


bot = WhatsappBot()
bot.EnviarMensagens()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for the source of the chat window DOM element to change. I haven't tested this code, and it could send program into endless loop.

```
import time
timeout = 10 # check every 10 seconds for messages
chatbox_xpath = "//div[@class='chatbox']" # representation only

while True:
    source = driver.find_element_by_xpath(chatbox_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML')
    time.sleep(timeout)
    if source != 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(chatbox_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML'):
       break
```

Comment: @AngelTm_ tbh I can't really tell what's going on because your variable names are not in English, plus I can't deduce what you are doing from the xpath either. Maybe it goes in the while loop you have there. Essentially you need to figure this out since its your bot and you are programming the functionality of it. Your question was quite vague to begin with, I refer you to [ask] for some tips on asking questions.

Comment: can i contact u somehow and explain it better?? i really need this xd

Comment: `while count < 3: ` should be replaced with `while True` and you have some sort of list defined outside of while loop `group_chat_src = []` then you then for loop through the groups. Each time you update the source code to `group_chat_src[grupo] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(chatbox_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML')` then inside for loop `if group_chat_src[grupo] != driver.find_element_by_xpath(chatbox_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML')` `# do stuff` otherwise `pass`. Now you need exit condition for while loop. That's all I can do bud.